# Як правильно має відмінюватися слово «коміт»?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Натрапив на один ресурс, де автор перекладу на українську ось так вживає слово `commit`.
В однині — `коміт` (приклад у тексті: «…перепише поточну гілку, щоб вона вказувала на потрібний **коміт**»).
У множині — `комміттов` (приклад у тексті: «Видалення **комміттов** з гілки»).
Я вважаю, що у множині більш правильно буде — `комітів`.
Що скажете?

Comment: Панові цїкаво вжив взятого якогось иноземного слова чи відзнайти питоме українське слово? _Запитання, які стосуються перекладу, мають містити переклад своїми словами (українською), контекст (також українською), і, бажано, варіанти, які автор знайшов в Інтернеті, з поясненням, чому ці варіанти не підходять._

Comment: @excellproj, не зовсім зрозуміло, що саме Ви питаєте: (а) як краще перекласти іменник «[commit](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_(version_control))» (я так розумію, мається на увазі в контексті [систем контроля версій](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Система_керування_версіями)), чи (б) як має відмінюватися слово «коміт» (за умови, що саме його ми обрали відповідником англійському «commit»), чи (в) і те, і інше?

Comment: @Sasha Дякую за уточнюючі питання: скоріше варіант (б). Так сказати як чуємо так и пишемо `commit`, то пишемо `коміт`, а де мається на увазі множина `commits`, то ...? Ось що хотілося дізнатися. Ось тут https://githowto.com/uk/removing_commits_from_a_branch автор вказав у заголовку `комміттов`(що здається є помилкою), а в тексті вживає  `коммітов` (Давайте зробимо швидку перевірку нашої історії **коммітов**.)

Comment: @Follower, Ви вживаєте літеру `ї` у словах `цїкаво` та `українською`. Очевидно, навмисно. Як Ви тоді розрізняєте вимову цих літер? В одному випадку вимовляється `[і]`, в іншому - `[йі]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Існують різні варіанти перекладу слів «commit» (іменник) і «to commit» (дієслово) українською. [Ось тут](//github.com/progit/progit2-uk/issues/135) Ви можете подивитись, які варіанти розглядали перекладачі книги «Pro Git». Врешті-решт вони зупинилися на прямому запозиченні «коміт».

Якщо написання слова в називному відмінку — «коміт», то очевидно, що в написанні «комміттов» (у заголовку «Видалення комміттов з гілки») міститься відразу декілька помилок:

- подвоєне «мм» (яке не може з'являтися в родовому відмінку множини, якщо його немає в називному відмінку однини);
- подвоєне «тт» (яке не може з'являтися в родовому відмінку множини, якщо його немає в називному відмінку однини);
- закінчення «ов» неправильне.

Як іменник-неістота чоловічого роду твердої групи [другої відміни](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par46II), «комі́т» має відмінюватися аналогічно до «[кларне́т](//uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.84.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.96.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.96_.D1.82.D0.B0_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.96_.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.96)» чи «[динамі́т](//uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%82#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.84.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.96.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.96_.D1.82.D0.B0_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.96_.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.96)»:

```
Відмінок |Однина            |Множина
---------+------------------+-----------
Називний |комі́т             |комі́ти
Родовий  |комі́та чи комі́ту? |комі́тів
Давальний|комі́ту, комі́тові  |комі́там
Знахідний|комі́т             |комі́ти
Орудний  |комі́том           |комі́тами
Місцевий |(у) комі́ті        |(у) комі́тах
Кличний  |комі́те            |комі́ти
```

Питання про закінчення родового відмінка однини («а» чи «у») я наразі вирішити не можу.

Comment: Додам, що в термінології IEEE, зокрема Software configuration management IEEE 828, комітом називається revision, ревізія, що також можна використовувати як "додати ревізію" або "опублікувати ревізію". А відмінювання коміта можна перевіряти за словом динамі́т, -ту, -тові (Голоскевич). Звичайно, ніяких динамітОв бути не може.

Comment: @ovnia, згідно Вашої логіки, у родовому відмінку має бути `коміту`, але Ви чомусь пишете `відмінювання коміта`.

Comment: @user2513149, хм, а якось не подумав, що закінчення можуть бути «-а» і «-у», просто на автоматі продублював із кларнета. «-А» чи «-у» в родовому — це ще відкрите питання.